# Why is the chronos password different from the root password?

Tags: passwords, root

My device is a Samsung Chromebook 4.

Most of the answers I find are confusing `chronos` and `root`. using the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (right facing arrow) you will be prompted to set a password for `chronos` (dev pw) by entering

```
user: chronos 
pw: test0000.
```

Followed by the command `chromeos-setdevpasswd`. However, that is not specifically the root password. If you enter `user: root` there is a completely different password that I have been unable to obtain from online searches.

Comment: Welcome SU @NOX-3N :) Your request isn't easy to understand. It will be good if you can edit it to make it a bit more clear. However, it's like you are referring two distinct account, `chronos` and `root` and you cannot modify this later as standard user.